# Can we do away with TURN server for WebRTC sessions to be successful for ALL the scenarios?

Tags: webrtc, ipv6, sdn, turn

Can we do away with TURN server for WebRTC sessions to be successful for ALL the scenarios?
By ALL the scenarios, I mean the two peers can be served by different ISPs and the traffic may be routed through multiple hops over the public internet.

If not, does IPv6 or SDN offer any solution to this?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking. TURN servers specifically exist because a connection cannot always realistically be achieved without one. If you don't use a TURN server, then ***no***, you're *not* always able to successfully connect in today's internet.

Comment: Since IPv6 doesn't do NAT, you typically don't have the problems which need TURN to solve. Users with IPv6 have public addresses because there are plenty of IPv6 addresses to go around. NAT was developed to postpone the IPv4 shortage until IPv6 became ubiquitous. IPv6 will restore the original premise of end-to-end connectivity around which IP was developed.

Comment: Note that you may still have problems with firewalls in an IPv6 scenario, which may still necessitate a TURN server.

Comment: @deceze, TURN gets around problems of NAT which has nothing to do with firewalls. IPv6 doesn't have NAT, so it doesn't need TURN, but it still can use firewalls.

Comment: @Ron TURN servers get around *connectivity problems*, where one or both sides cannot open an incoming port. NAT is one possible cause of this, but firewalls may as well prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if a TURN server is enough to get ICE connectivity in WebRTC, then yes. All TURN servers also implement STUN, so it should be enough.